# Spacing between item and description using description list

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem, description

How can I get the same result as the code below without having to use `\quad` spacing? Is there any parameter in `enumitem` to adjust the horizontal spacing?

```
\begin{description}
\item{Item 1} \quad Description 1
\item{Item 2} \quad Description 2
\end{description}
```

MWE for alignment issue:

```
\documentclass{book}

%%% Paper format %%%
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,headheight=7mm,headsep=5mm,marginparsep=5mm,marginparwidth=10mm]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Lista de Simbolos}
\begin{description}[labelsep=4em, align=left]
\item[$b$] Taxa agregada de bits alcançável para o sistema
\item[$H(f)$] Espectro do canal
\item[$H_k$] Ganho do $k$-ésimo subcanal
\item[$P_x$] Potência total de transmissão
\item[$s_k$] Densidade espectral de potência do sinal no $k$-ésimo subcanal
\item[$Sx(f)$] Densidade espectral de potência do sinal na frequência contínua
\item[$Sn(f)$] Densidade espectral de potência do AWGN na frequência contínua
\item[$\text{SNR}_k$] Razão sinal-ruído no subcanal $k$
\item[$\mathbf{X}$] Vetor correspondente ao símbolo DMT
\item[$\mathbf{X}_+$] Vetor de subsímbolos dos tons positivos do símbolo DMT.
\item[$X_k$] Subsímbolo no $k$-ésimo tom do símbolo DMT
\item[$\Gamma$] \textsl[Gap] de SNR a capacidade
\item[$\Delta f$] Largura de banda do subcanal (espaçamento tonal).
\item[$\sigma_k$] Densidade espectral de potência do AWGN no $k$-ésimo subcanal
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameter `labelsep` gives the distance between the label and the following text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelsep=1em]
\item[first matter] \lipsum[1]
\item[some other matter] \lipsum[1]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Note how I use square brackets around the label content for `description`.  I think it is pretty standard that `\quad` has a length of `1em`, but that may depend on the document class your using.

If you want to change how the labels and for each label are positioned you can use the parameters `labelwidth` and `labelindent`.

```
\chapter*{Lista de Simbolos}
\begin{description}[labelsep=4em, align=left, labelwidth=1in,labelindent=1cm]
  \item[$b$] Taxa agregada de bits alcançável para o sistema
  \item[$H(f)$] Espectro do canal
  \item[$H_k$] Ganho do $k$-ésimo subcanal
  \item[$P_x$] Potência total de transmissão
  \item[$s_k$] Densidade espectral de potência do sinal no $k$-ésimo subcanal
  \item[$Sx(f)$] Densidade espectral de potência do sinal na frequência contínua
  \item[$Sn(f)$] Densidade espectral de potência do AWGN na frequência contínua
  \item[$\text{SNR}_k$] Razão sinal-ruído no subcanal $k$
  \item[$\mathbf{X}$] Vetor correspondente ao símbolo DMT
  \item[$\mathbf{X}_+$] Vetor de subsímbolos dos tons positivos do símbolo DMT.
  \item[$X_k$] Subsímbolo no $k$-ésimo tom do símbolo DMT
  \item[$\Gamma$] \textsl{Gap} de SNR a capacidade
  \item[$\Delta f$] Largura de banda do subcanal (espaçamento tonal).
  \item[$\sigma_k$] Densidade espectral de potência do AWGN no $k$-ésimo subcanal
\end{description}
```

Here, the values I chose are *rather dramatic*.  I'm sure you'll want something more conservative.

[image]

**Some other points**

Instead of writing `\textsl[Gap]` you want to write `\textsl{Gap}`.  This **is different** from how `\item` handles things.  Basically, `\textsl` has a mandatory argument that you pass to it through curly brackets.  `\item`, on the other hand, has an *optional* argument for *overriding* the label contents (which is what you want to do in a `description` environment).

Also, I'm not sure how you're handling your font encoding, but you might want to put something like `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble.  However, I'm not really much of an authority on fonts, and don't necessarily know the best approach to take here.

Comment: Thank you. "\begin{description}[labelsep=4em, align=left]" worked as I wanted. However, now the descriptions are aligned with the chapter title (it is a list of acronyms), whereas the labels should be aligned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I edited the original post with the example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it appears exactly as I wanted.

Comment: @igorauad I've added a few more pointers to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, once again. I'm handling the font issue in the original document with \usepackage[brazil]{babel}, \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}. Thanks for the tip on textsl.

Comment: Just to clarify something: `inputenc` is not related to font encoding but to the encoding of the source files. For font encoding one wants to use `fontenc`.